# Importing struct with plt scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm struck on a problem with a simple scheme application. 
In one file (dataloader.ss), I define a struct :

```
(define-struct book-category (id name books))
```

But I can't use the structure in another file.
What I try is, in dataloader.ss, to export the structure with

```
(provide book-category)
```

And in the other file, I import :

```
(require "dataloader.ss").
```

But a call to one of the struct functions irremediably fails :
For example

```
(make-book-category 2 "test" '())
```

gives me :

> reference to an identifier before its
>   definition: make-book-category

On the other hand, if I redefine the struct in the 2nd file, it tells me :
"module: identifier is already imported in: book-category"
so, I guess the import works at least partially. But I still can't access the associated functions. Is there something else to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it, i must export with the struct-out keyword, as in

```
(provide  (struct-out book-category))
```